# Calendar animation like IOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

How to make animation like calendar app of iphone device IOS 7?
While selecting month in the Year view, very smooth animation is performed.
How i can achieve this animation?

Thanks for your time for reading & best of luck.

Comment: What have you tried??? Have you done any research before asking and have you got any code to share?? Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: yes, i research alot, till now i didnt got what i looking for? I have implement UICollectionView to show year view & show month view simple animation, but im looking forward like device calendar animation.

Comment: Have you attempted this by yourself???

Comment: yes, i attempted, but im not getting calendar animation like IOS 7 calendar app.

Comment: Please share what you have done then.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a `Layout-to-Layout` transition.

Essentially it is one collection view that is animated between different layouts to create the zooming in/out effect.

The same this is used in the Photos app.

You can read more about it here...

Erm... just finding a link.

Session 218 video from WWDC 2013. This has what you're looking for.